# Add method doesn't work for ArrayList of type String

Tags: java

I have tried to use the add method to add some Strings to my ArrayList of type Name. Name stores firstName and familyName. All I tried to do is pass the firstName and familyName using the scanner but it just doesn't seem to be that easy. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Name> register = new ArrayList<Name>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter first name:");
            String firstName = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter last name:");
            String secondName = sc.nextLine();

            register.add(firstName, secondName);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Check how you declare the register variable:

```
ArrayList<Name> register = new ArrayList<Name>();
```

It is an ArrayList of a specific type, of `Name`. So this means that you need to add Name objects to your ArrayList, not two Strings. So you should do this. Consider changing this:

```
register.add(firstName, secondName);
```

to something like this:

```
// assuming Name has a constructor that accepts two Strings
register.add(new Name(firstName, secondName));
```

Comment: Replied in 66s :) just perfect

Comment: thank you, sir! knew there must be something wrong with this. forgot to add that. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If your Name class like this :

```
public class Name 
{
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getSecondName() {
      return secondName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
      this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
      this.secondName = secondName;
   }
}
```

You can add the Object to ArrayList like :

```
Name name = new Name();
name.setFirstName(firstName);
name.setSecondName(secondName);

register.add(name);
```